# Swift add integers from CKRecord return

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have a `CKRecord` that returns a list of 1s and -1s.  I need to add all of these together to get a net value, but can't figure it out.

Here's a bit of the code:

```
let freezerQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "PumpingEntry", predicate: predicate)
let freezerSort = NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "FreezerQuantity", ascending: false)
freezerQuery.sortDescriptors = [freezerSort]

var freezerOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: freezerQuery)
freezerOperation.desiredKeys = ["FreezerQuantity"]
freezerOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in
    let freezerInteger: Int = record.object(forKey: "FreezerQuantity") as! Int

    let freezerTotel = ?????????????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your `freezerTotal` variable outside of the block. Then simply add `freezerInteger` to `freezerTotal`.

```
var freezerTotal = 0
freezerOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in
    let freezerInteger: Int = record.object(forKey: "FreezerQuantity") as! Int
    freezerTotal += freezerInteger
}
```

And then you can make use of the total in the operation's completion block:

```
freezerOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) in
    // do something with the total
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!